# jQM pagecontainer loading multiple pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jqm 1.4.5 and having trouble using the pagecontainer's `load` method.  I am choosing to split my webapp into multiple html files for ease of management (I know some of you may disagree, but that's a discussion for another day).  In my `index.html` file, I can successfully load external `.html` files into the DOM, but the problem is when there is more than one page in the file.  I would expect that it would insert any `div` that has `data-role="page"`, but it only loads the first into the DOM.  For example, if I have the following code..

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-dom-cache="true">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        ...stuff...
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-dom-cache="true">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        ...stuff...
    </div>
</div>
```

...only `page1` will be loaded into the DONM.  `page2` will not.  I know this because of two things... all references to anything in `page2` fail and, when I look at the source in Chrome, `page2` is simply not there.  In order for me to get it into the DOM, I make `page2` a separate file, such as `page2.html`.  While I do this for most of the site, this isn't ideal 100% of the time - for example, if two pages are extremely closely related (for example, a login page and a lost password page).

I am not sure how to proceed with this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is by design and is documented. Look at the jQM docs here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

> Note: You cannot link to a multipage document with Ajax navigation active because the framework will only load the first page it finds, not the full set of internal pages. In these cases, you must link without Ajax (see next section) for a full page refresh to prevent potential hash collisions. There is currently a **[subpage](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget)** plugin that makes it possible to load in multi-page documents.